# Keras "list index out of range" when saving a model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm getting a problem when I want to save my keras model using the model.save method :

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here is the model :

```
    ### Model ###
    # 3 inputs
    inputA = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(100,))
    inputB = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(100,))
    inputC = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(4,))

    # First branch
    x = tf.keras.models.Sequential()(inputA)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(350, activation="relu")(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(250, activation="relu")(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(150, activation="relu")(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="relu")(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation="relu")(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(25, activation="relu")(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="relu")(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)
    x = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputA, outputs=x)

    # Second branch
    y = tf.keras.models.Sequential()(inputB)
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(350, activation="relu")(y)
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(y)
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(250, activation="relu")(y)
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(y)
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(150, activation="relu")(y)
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(y)
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="relu")(y)
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(y)
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation="relu")(y)
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(y)
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(25, activation="relu")(y)
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(y)
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="relu")(y)
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(y)
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(y)
    y = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputB, outputs=y)

    # Third branch
    w = tf.keras.models.Sequential()(inputC)
    w = tf.keras.layers.Dense(200, activation="relu")(w)
    w = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(w)
    w = tf.keras.layers.Dense(200, activation="relu")(w)
    w = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(w)
    w = tf.keras.layers.Dense(150, activation="relu")(w)
    w = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(w)
    w = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="relu")(w)
    w = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(w)
    w = tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation="relu")(w)
    w = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(w)
    w = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(w)
    w = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputC, outputs=w)

    # Concatenate outputs
    combined = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([x.output, y.output, w.output])

    # Last branch with combined
    z = tf.keras.layers.Dense(200, activation="relu")(combined)
    z = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(z)
    z = tf.keras.layers.Dense(200, activation="relu")(z)
    z = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(z)
    z = tf.keras.layers.Dense(150, activation="relu")(z)
    z = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(z)
    z = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="relu")(z)
    z = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(z)
    z = tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation="relu")(z)
    z = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(z)
    z = tf.keras.layers.Dense(25, activation="relu")(z)
    z = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(z)
    z = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(z) #softmax ou sigmoid

    model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[x.input, y.input, w.input], outputs=z)
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
    model.fit(x=[X1, X2, X3], y=y1, batch_size=128, epochs=nb_epoch, verbose=2)

    # Evaluation on test set
    ...

    # Sauvegarde du model
    model.save("path/to/my/model/location")
```

Here is the complete error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "reseauNeurone.py", line 230, in MLP
    model.save("/Users/x/Documents/Cours/DI5/S9/Projet IA/Model")
  File "/Users/x/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1979, in save
    signatures, options)
  File "/Users/x/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/save.py", line 134, in save_model
    signatures, options)
  File "/Users/x/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/save.py", line 80, in save
    save_lib.save(model, filepath, signatures, options)
  File "/Users/x/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/save.py", line 976, in save
    obj, export_dir, signatures, options, meta_graph_def)
  File "/Users/x/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/save.py", line 1076, in _build_meta_graph
    asset_info.asset_index)
  File "/Users/x/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/save.py", line 721, in _serialize_object_graph
    saveable_view.function_name_map)
  File "/Users/x/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/save.py", line 761, in _write_object_proto
    metadata=obj._tracking_metadata)
  File "/Users/x/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 3011, in _tracking_metadata
    return self._trackable_saved_model_saver.tracking_metadata
  File "/Users/x/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/base_serialization.py", line 54, in tracking_metadata
    return json_utils.Encoder().encode(self.python_properties)
  File "/Users/x/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/layer_serialization.py", line 41, in python_properties
    return self._python_properties_internal()
  File "/Users/x/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/model_serialization.py", line 35, in _python_properties_internal
    metadata = super(ModelSavedModelSaver, self)._python_properties_internal()
  File "/Users/x/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/layer_serialization.py", line 59, in _python_properties_internal
    metadata.update(get_config(self.obj))
  File "/Users/x/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/layer_serialization.py", line 118, in get_config
    config = generic_utils.serialize_keras_object(obj)['config']
  File "/Users/x/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 245, in serialize_keras_object
    config = instance.get_config()
  File "/Users/x/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py", line 598, in get_config
    return copy.deepcopy(get_network_config(self))
  File "/Users/x/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py", line 1261, in get_network_config
    kept_nodes = 1 if _should_skip_first_node(layer) else 0
  File "/Users/x/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py", line 1033, in _should_skip_first_node
    isinstance(layer._layers[0], input_layer_module.InputLayer))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have also tried using model.get_config or using json to save the model, but the error remains the same.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem and therefore how to successfully save the model ?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you reviewed this page? https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/43561

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your code.
The issue was the same for x,y,z. You were mixing Keras Functional API with Sequential Models.

Just comment out the Sequential Model and pass the input to your first dense layer.

```
    #x = tf.keras.models.Sequential()(inputA)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(350, activation="relu")(inputA)
```

Here is the whole code. I was able to save your model.

```
### Model ###
    # 3 inputs
    inputA = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(100,))
    inputB = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(100,))
    inputC = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(4,))

    # First branch
    #x = tf.keras.models.Sequential()(inputA)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(350, activation="relu")(inputA)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(250, activation="relu")(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(150, activation="relu")(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="relu")(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation="relu")(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(25, activation="relu")(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="relu")(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)
    x = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputA, outputs=x)

    # Second branch
    #y = tf.keras.models.Sequential()(inputB)
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(350, activation="relu")(inputB)
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(y)
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(250, activation="relu")(y)
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(y)
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(150, activation="relu")(y)
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(y)
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="relu")(y)
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(y)
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation="relu")(y)
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(y)
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(25, activation="relu")(y)
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(y)
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="relu")(y)
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(y)
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(y)
    y = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputB, outputs=y)

    # Third branch
    #w = tf.keras.models.Sequential()(inputC)
    w = tf.keras.layers.Dense(200, activation="relu")(inputC)
    w = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(w)
    w = tf.keras.layers.Dense(200, activation="relu")(w)
    w = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(w)
    w = tf.keras.layers.Dense(150, activation="relu")(w)
    w = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(w)
    w = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="relu")(w)
    w = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(w)
    w = tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation="relu")(w)
    w = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(w)
    w = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(w)
    w = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputC, outputs=w)

    # Concatenate outputs
    combined = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([x.output, y.output, w.output])

    # Last branch with combined
    z = tf.keras.layers.Dense(200, activation="relu")(combined)
    z = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(z)
    z = tf.keras.layers.Dense(200, activation="relu")(z)
    z = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(z)
    z = tf.keras.layers.Dense(150, activation="relu")(z)
    z = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(z)
    z = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="relu")(z)
    z = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(z)
    z = tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation="relu")(z)
    z = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(z)
    z = tf.keras.layers.Dense(25, activation="relu")(z)
    z = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(z)
    z = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(z) #softmax ou sigmoid

    model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[x.input, y.input, w.input], outputs=z)
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
    model.fit(x=[X1, X2, X3], y=y1, batch_size=128, epochs=nb_epoch, verbose=2)

    # Evaluation on test set
    ...

    # Sauvegarde du model
    model.save("path/to/my/model/location")
```